# Stack UITableView Cells on top of eachother

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, cell

I am creating an app where I am using a list view as a screen. When I click the item I want the items to "stack on eachother" (think of metal flaps), [image]

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
   {
     int i = 0;
     for(UITableViewCell *v in [self.tableView subviews])
     {
        NSLog(@"%d",i);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
          if(i == 0)
          {
             [v setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50 - (indexPath.row + 200)-i, self.view.frame.size.height, 100)];
          }
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
    [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    i++;
}


}
```

The table view cells do translate, how ever I cannot achieve the "semi overlapping effect", (I am guessing apple makes table view cells linear layouts relative to each other). Is there a way to override this and make them semi over lap at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subview to the cell's contentView that extends below the bottom of the cell if you want it to overlap the cell below. Be sure to set the contentView's clipsToBounds property to NO (it's YES by default).

Comment: I am not sure that will work. i need them to "stop" at a point ie. say you can see like 6 of them i need the bottom one to stop at the bottom one after under it. I think what you say might work, but is there no way get them to act independently?

Comment: does not work, the subviews of ui table view is uitableviewcellwrapper, I cannot get access to the actual cell and manipulate them for some reason.